# How do I add an Implementation-Version value to a jar manifest using Maven?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, jar, manifest

I'd like to add an Implementation-Version line to a manifest in my jar file that reflects the POM version number. I can't for the life of me work out how to do this using the jar plugin.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You would use the Maven Archiver:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

This will add the following to the manifest file:

```
Implementation-Title: ${pom.name}
Implementation-Version: ${pom.version}
Implementation-Vendor-Id: ${pom.groupId}
Implementation-Vendor: ${pom.organization.name}
```

Comment: ${buildNumber}? How about this variable?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't needed. I was just showing other Implementation values to set.

Comment: Anytime! I have run into this issue before so I am just glad I can share what I learned with someone else :-)

Comment: To make it work for an EAR: `<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>`

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a one-liner property? I'm wondering if it works in a similar way to: `<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>`