# How do I add an Implementation-Version value to a jar manifest using Maven's assembly plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, jar, manifest

I'd like to add an Implementation-Version line to a manifest in my jar file that reflects the POM version number, using the maven assembly plugin.

Note that this is similar but different to [another of my recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921667/how-do-i-add-an-implementation-version-value-to-a-jar-manifest-using-maven/921753) about the jar plugin.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually I'm a fool.. you do it in exactly the same way, i.e.

```
<configuration>
 <archive>
  <manifest>
   <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
  </manifest>
 </archive>
</configuration>
```

Silly question. Should have tried that first, really.