# Retrieve version from maven pom.xml in code

Tags: java, maven, version

What is the simplest way to retrieve version number from maven's pom.xml in code, i.e., programatically?

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java, you can:

1. Create a `.properties` file in (most commonly) your `src/main/resources` directory (but in step 4 you could tell it to look elsewhere).
2. Set the value of some property in your `.properties` file using the standard Maven property for project version:

   ```
   foo.bar=${project.version}
   ```
3. In your Java code, load the value from the properties file as a resource from the classpath (google for copious examples of how to do this, but [here's an example for starters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26573884/1470257)).
4. In Maven, enable resource filtering. This will cause Maven to copy that file into your output classes and translate the resource during that copy, interpreting the property.  You can find some info [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files) but you mostly just do this in your pom:

   ```xml
   <build>
     <resources>
       <resource>
         <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
         <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
     </resources>   
   </build>
   ```

You can also get to other standard properties like `project.name`, `project.description`, or even arbitrary properties you put in your pom `<properties>`, etc.  Resource filtering, combined with Maven profiles, can give you variable build behavior at build time.  When you specify a profile at runtime with `-PmyProfile`, that can enable properties that then can show up in your build.

Comment: I found a code [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime) that no change Maven config.

Comment: Beware of using filtering directly on `src/main/resources`, as this may process all files located in this directory, including binaries files. To avoid unpredictable behaviours, it's better to do filtering on a `src/main/resources-filtered` directory, [as suggested here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). Anyway, thank you for this nice trick!

Comment: The answer below using the MavenXppReader to get the actual model is really useful, as it doesn't need to run anything to find the value.  In cases where you need to know the version before anything is run, look at the answers below; it was very helpful for me to let gradle know what version a checked out maven project has, so I could know the output jar location beforehand.

Comment: Beware that this does not work if using it during unit testing. If you need the project information during unit testing see answer by @kriegaex

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501017/maven-resource-filtering-not-working-because-of-spring-boot-dependency), if you are using spring boot, you need to use `@project.version@` instead of `${project.version}`

Answer (score 132):

The accepted answer may be the best and most stable way to get a version number into an application ***statically***, but does not actually answer the original question: How to retrieve the artifact's version number from pom.xml? Thus, I want to offer an alternative showing how to do it ***dynamically*** during runtime:

You can use Maven itself. To be more exact, you can use a Maven library.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And then do something like this in Java:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
        System.out.println(model.getId());
        System.out.println(model.getGroupId());
        System.out.println(model.getArtifactId());
        System.out.println(model.getVersion());
    }
}
```

The console log is as follows:

```
de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:my-artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
de.scrum-master.stackoverflow
my-artifact
1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

---

**Update 2017-10-31:** In order to answer Simon Sobisch's follow-up question I modified the example like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.apache.maven.model.Model;
import org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
    Model model;
    if ((new File("pom.xml")).exists())
      model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
    else
      model = reader.read(
        new InputStreamReader(
          Application.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "/META-INF/maven/de.scrum-master.stackoverflow/aspectj-introduce-method/pom.xml"
          )
        )
      );
    System.out.println(model.getId());
    System.out.println(model.getGroupId());
    System.out.println(model.getArtifactId());
    System.out.println(model.getVersion());
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nearly identical to what I use and works fine when started from eclipse, but doesn't when started from the normal `package`d jar (dependency classes aren't integrated) and doesn't work when packaged with maven-assembly-plugin `jar-with-dependencies` I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: pom.xml` (it is in the final jar as `META-INF/maven/my.package/myapp/pom.xml`) - any hints how to solve this?

Comment: My solution is meant to work dynamically in development environments, e.g. when used in tests or tools started from IDE or console. The accepted answer to this question shows several ways to package the version number statically into your artifacts. I was not assuming that pom.xml would be available within JARs at all. Nice for you that you have it there, though. Maybe you could just adjust the path when opening the file reader and maybe make it dependent on the classloader situation. I would have to try for myself. Feel free to ask follow-up questions if this does not help.

Comment: Hi @SimonSobisch, I have just updated my answer so as to show you how to do what you want. But please be aware of the fact that I just did it quick & dirty, I do not particularly like the code with the nested constructors.

Comment: I'm just extending a tool so it can lookup usages of specific artifacts in repository directory trees and already included maven-model. Now I know how to use it, thanks :)

Answer (score 81):

Packaged artifacts contain a `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties` file which content looks like:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Sun Feb 21 23:38:24 GMT 2010
version=2.5
groupId=commons-lang
artifactId=commons-lang
```

Many applications use this file to read the application/jar version at runtime, there is zero setup required.

The only problem with the above approach is that this file is (currently) generated during the `package` phase and will thus not be present during tests, etc (there is a Jira issue to change this, see [MJAR-76](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-76)). If this is an issue for you, then the approach described by Alex is the way to go.

Comment: for people looking for an example reading the properties, this post goes over several methods - http://www.javablog.fr/javaspring-get-and-display-the-version-from-manifest-mf.html

Comment: New link for MJAR-76: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAR-76

Comment: Resume: prop.load(Starter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/myGroupId/myArtefactId/pom.properties"));

Answer (score 60):

There is also the method described in [Easy way to display your apps version number using Maven](https://web.archive.org/web/20120121133235/http://www.christophkiehl.com/easy-way-to-display-your-apps-version-using-maven-and-manifest):

Add this to pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>test.App</mainClass>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              true
            </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then use this:

```
App.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

I have found this method to be simpler.

Comment: -1 - This solution didn't work for me; the value of `getImplementationVersion()` was `null`. (maven version 3.0.4)

Comment: depending on the phase... only works when the artifact is being packaged, so does not work on unit tests :-/

Comment: For `.war` artifacts, remember to use `maven-war-plugin` instead of `maven-jar-plugin`

Comment: For me, this does work in **Tomcat 8**, but doesn't work in **Tomcat 7** (`getImplementationVersion()` returns null).

Comment: It works when you compile a jar, otherwise doesn't

Comment: Thanks. This works for me – except that if I run the app in the IDE, it doesn’t appear to run out of the JAR file and hence picks up the version number as null (i.e., same problem as unit tests).

Is there a way to get Netbeans (using v18) to run the jar file and hence get the same effect as launching outside the IDE?

Answer (score 27):

If you use mvn packaging such as jar or war, use:

```
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

It reads a property "Implementation-Version" of the generated META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (that is set to the pom.xml's version) in the archive.

Comment: If looking for how to include "Implementation-Version" to MANIFEST.MF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921667/how-do-i-add-an-implementation-version-value-to-a-jar-manifest-using-maven

Comment: This seems to be an incomplete answer that only applies to certain situations. Did not work for my TestNG project, probably due to lacking manifest packaging.

Answer (score 23):

To complement what @kieste has posted, which I think is the best way to have Maven build informations available in your code if you're using Spring-boot: the documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info is very useful.

You just need to activate actuators, and add the properties you need in your `application.properties` or `application.yml`

```
Automatic property expansion using Maven

You can automatically expand info properties from the Maven project using resource filtering. If you use the spring-boot-starter-parent you can then refer to your Maven ‘project properties’ via @..@ placeholders, e.g.

project.artifactId=myproject
project.name=Demo
project.version=X.X.X.X
project.description=Demo project for info endpoint
info.build.artifact=@project.artifactId@
info.build.name=@project.name@
info.build.description=@project.description@
info.build.version=@project.version@
```

Comment: This answer helped in that I needed to use the @..@ notation to read the properties from maven. Something else is using the ${..} notation and it was conflicting.

Answer (score 15):

When using spring boot, this link might be useful: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto-properties-and-configuration

With spring-boot-starter-parent you just need to add the following to your application config file:

```
# get values from pom.xml
pom.version=@project.version@
```

After that the value is available like this:

```
@Value("${pom.version}")
private String pomVersion;
```

Comment: Is this possible with gradle?

Comment: @AdamHughes https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto-automatic-expansion-gradle

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes the Maven command line is sufficient when scripting something related to the project version, e.g. for artifact retrieval via URL from a repository:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Usage example:

```bash
VERSION=$( mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout )
ARTIFACT_ID=$( mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout )
GROUP_ID_URL=$( mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout | sed -e 's#\.#/#g' )
curl -f -S -O http://REPO-URL/mvn-repos/${GROUP_ID_URL}/${ARTIFACT_ID}/${VERSION}/${ARTIFACT_ID}-${VERSION}.jar
```

Comment: It's fine, just incredibly slow, especially if the artifacts aren't downloaded yet.

Comment: I completely agree with that :-( The only advantage is that it works with every kind of Maven project/module, even those which inherit their version from some parent pom.xml

Answer (score 6):

Use this Library for the ease of a simple solution. Add to the manifest whatever you need and then query by string.

```
 System.out.println("JAR was created by " + Manifests.read("Created-By"));
```

http://manifests.jcabi.com/index.html

Answer (score 5):

```
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.2.2</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                     </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
```

Get Version using `this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`

PS Don't forget to add:

```
<manifest>
    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you . This worked for my project in RapidClipse / Vaadin + Maven 3.6.3

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**: If you are using Spring Boot, your pom.xml should already contain **spring-boot-maven-plugin**. You just need to add the following configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-info</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It instructs the plugin to execute also build-info goal, which is not run by default. This generates build meta-data about your application, which includes artifact version, build time and more.

**Step2:** Accessing Build Properties with buildProperties bean. In our case we create a restResource to access to this build info in our webapp

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BuildInfoResource {
    @Autowired
    private BuildProperties buildProperties;

    
    @GetMapping("/build-info")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getBuildInfo() {
        Map<String, String> buildInfo = new HashMap();
        buildInfo.put("appName", buildProperties.getName());
        buildInfo.put("appArtifactId", buildProperties.getArtifact());
        buildInfo.put("appVersion", buildProperties.getVersion());
        buildInfo.put("appBuildDateTime", buildProperties.getTime());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(buldInfo);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy and no configuration is needed if you use Spring with Maven.
According to the [“Automatic Property Expansion Using Maven”](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.expand-properties.maven) official documentation you can automatically expand properties from the Maven project by using resource filtering. If you use the spring-boot-starter-parent, you can then refer to your Maven ‘project properties’ with @..@ placeholders, as shown in the following example:

```
project.version=@project.version@
project.artifactId=@project.artifactId@
```

And you can retrieve it with @Value annotation in any class:

```
@Value("${project.artifactId}@${project.version}")
private String RELEASE;
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in my daytime job. Even though many of the answers will help to find the version for a specific artifact, we needed to get the version for modules/jars that are not a direct dependency of the application. The classpath is assembled from multiple modules when the application starts, the main application module has no knowledge of how many jars are added later.

That's why I came up with a different solution, which may be a little more elegant than having to read XML or properties from jar files.

## The idea

1. use a Java service loader approach to be able to add as many components/artifacts later, which can contribute their own versions at runtime. Create a very lightweight library with just a few lines of code to read, find, filter and sort all of the artifact versions on the classpath.
2. Create a maven source code generator plugin that generates the service implementation for each of the modules at compile time, package a very simple service in each of the jars.

## The solution

Part one of the solution is the `artifact-version-service` library, which can be found on [github](https://github.com/swesteme/artifact-version-service) and [MavenCentral](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.westemeyer/artifact-version-service) now. It covers the service definition and a few ways to get the artifact versions at runtime.

Part two is the `artifact-version-maven-plugin`, which can also be found on [github](https://github.com/swesteme/artifact-version-maven-plugin) and [MavenCentral](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.westemeyer/artifact-version-maven-plugin). It is used to have a hassle-free generator implementing the service definition for each of the artifacts.

## Examples

#### Fetching all modules with coordinates

No more reading jar manifests, just a simple method call:

```java
// iterate list of artifact dependencies
for (Artifact artifact : ArtifactVersionCollector.collectArtifacts()) {
    // print simple artifact string example
    System.out.println("artifact = " + artifact);
}
```

A sorted set of artifacts is returned. To modify the sorting order, provide a custom comparator:

```java
new ArtifactVersionCollector(Comparator.comparing(Artifact::getVersion)).collect();
```

This way the list of artifacts is returned sorted by version numbers.

#### Find a specific artifact

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifact("de.westemeyer", "artifact-version-service");
```

Fetches the version details for a specific artifact.

#### Find artifacts with matching groupId(s)

Find all artifacts with groupId `de.westemeyer` (exact match):

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifactsByGroupId("de.westemeyer", true);
```

Find all artifacts where groupId *starts with* `de.westemeyer`:

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifactsByGroupId("de.westemeyer", false);
```

Sort result by version number:

```java
new ArtifactVersionCollector(Comparator.comparing(Artifact::getVersion)).artifactsByGroupId("de.", false);
```

#### Implement custom actions on list of artifacts

By supplying a lambda, the very first example could be implemented like this:

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.iterateArtifacts(a -> {
    System.out.println(a);
    return false;
});
```

## Installation

Add these two tags to all `pom.xml` files, or maybe to a company master pom somewhere:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>de.westemeyer</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-version-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate-service</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.westemeyer</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-version-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Feedback

It would be great if maybe some people could give the solution a try. Getting feedback about whether you think the solution fits your needs would be even better. So please don't hesitate to add a new issue on any of the github projects if you have any suggestions, feature requests, problems, whatsoever.

## Licence

All of the source code is open source, free to use even for commercial products (MIT licence).

Comment: This is cool, going to give it a try

Comment: Great, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Hey @jj33, I have created a new release to include additional fields as you suggested on github. Hope it turns out to be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [ketankk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54589733/10251345):

Unfortunately, adding this messed with how my application dealt with resources:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>   
</build>
```

But using this inside maven-assemble-plugin's < manifest > tag did the trick:

```
<addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
<addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
```

So I was able to get version using

```
String version = getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:** Because I remember this often referred-to question after having [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791885/1082681) it a few years ago, showing a dynamic version actually accessing Maven POM infos dynamically (e.g. also during tests), today I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68321439/1082681) which involved accessing module A's Maven info from another module B.

I thought about it for a moment and spontaneously had the idea to use a **special annotation**, applying it to a package declaration in **`package-info.java`**. I also created a multi-module example project on GitHub. I do not want to repeat the whole answer, so please see solution B in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68324028/1082681). The Maven setup involves **Templating Maven Plugin**, but could also be solved in a more verbose way using a combination of resource filtering and adding generated sources directory to the build via Build Helper Maven. I wanted to avoid that, so I simply used Templating Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer worked for me once in the step #2 I changed `${project.version}` to `${pom.version}`

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33217158)