# Verify dependencies in a Maven build

Tags: testing, maven, dependency-management

Is there a way to write a test that checks Maven dependencies?

In our project, we found these problems:

- Some parts of the project use `commons-io:commons-io`, others used `org.apache.commons:commons-io`
- The wrong version of a dependency was used
- `stax` uses the versions `1.0-2` and `1.0.1`. Using the automatic dependency resolution, `1.0-2` wins.

So what I want is to write a test case which takes the current dependency tree as input and runs a couple of checks on it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Test
public void testCommonsIo() throws Exception {
    assertDependencyVersion("commons-io", "commons-io", "2.0");
}

private void assertDependencyVersion(final String groupId, 
        final String artifactId, final String expectedVersion) 
        throws IOException {

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/META-INF/maven/");
    sb.append(groupId).append("/").append(artifactId);
    sb.append("/pom.properties");
    final String resourcePath = sb.toString();

    final InputStream propertiesStream = this.getClass()
        .getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
    assertNotNull("no dependency found: " + groupId + ":" + artifactId, 
        propertiesStream);

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(propertiesStream);

    assertEquals("group", groupId, properties.getProperty("groupId"));
    assertEquals("artifact", artifactId, properties.getProperty("artifactId"));
    assertEquals("version", expectedVersion, properties.getProperty("version"));
}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code/3698409#3698409) too.

---

Here is an assert method for StAX and other dependencies which don't contain `pom.properties` just `manifest.mf`. Maybe it would worth caching the `Properties` instances if there are lots of `assertDependencyByMetaInf` calls.

```
@Test
public void testStaxDependency() throws Exception {
    assertDependencyByMetaInf("StAX", "1.0.1");
}

private void assertDependencyByMetaInf(final String specTitle, 
        final String expectedSpecVersion) throws IOException {
    final ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    final String resourcePath = "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
    final Enumeration<URL> resources = cl.getResources(resourcePath);

    boolean found = false;
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        final URL url = resources.nextElement();
        final InputStream metaInfStream = url.openStream();

        final Properties metaInf = new Properties();
        metaInf.load(metaInfStream);

        final String metaInfSpecTitle = 
            metaInf.getProperty("Specification-Title");
        if (!specTitle.equals(metaInfSpecTitle)) {
            continue;
        }

        final String specVersion = 
            metaInf.getProperty("Specification-Version");
        assertEquals("version mismatch for " + specTitle, 
            expectedSpecVersion, specVersion);
        found = true;
    }
    assertTrue("missing dependency: " + specTitle, found);
}
```

Comment: -1 All JARs that I checked only contain a pom.properties file for the artifact itself. None of the dependencies are included.

Comment: Transitive dependencies also are on the classpath, so `getResourceAsStream` find their `pom.properties`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Changed my vote. Note: Some JARs from Maven Central don't have a pom.properties entry :-( For example stax-api (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cstax%7Cstax-api%7C1.0.1%7Cjar)

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from palacsint, here is another approach: Count how often a class is on the classpath and print the URLs if there is more than one.

```
private void assertOnceOnClassPath( String resourcePath ) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();

    Enumeration<URL> resources = cl.getResources( resourcePath );
    List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>();
    while( resources.hasMoreElements() ) {
        URL url = resources.nextElement();
        urls.add( url );
    }

    if( urls.size() != 1 ) {
        fail( "Expected exactly 1 item:\n" + StringUtils.join( urls, "\n" ) );
    }
}
```