# Logback config -- how to include Spring Application Version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

For analysis purposes, I want to log the application version in all log entries (ideally I would want to do this by editing the logback-spring.xml file instead of writing any Java code).

I'm am already logging spring application name successfully.

Note example startup up log message that shows correct application version.

As per my grade build -- am I updating the manifest file with the correct implementation-version. For Spring build actuator purposes I'm also setting info.build.version=${version}.

See below example -- I'm not sure what to put in ??? to correctly log the application version. I'm tried a number of keys including: info.build.version, application.version, spring.application.version, etc ..

```
 <springProperty name="APP_NAME" source="spring.application.name"/>

 <springProperty name="APP_VERSION" source="???"/>

 <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     <encoder>
         <pattern> version=${APP_VERISON} site=${APP_NAME}  %msg%n </pattern>
     </encoder>
 </appender>
```

> Starting Application v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT with PID 14147

Comment: This will help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code

Comment: Have you tried using `${info.build.version}` in the logging pattern?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda - correct I've tried ${info.build.version}

Comment: Have you tried generating build info file http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/build-info-mojo.html ?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda I'm using Gradle and injecting info.build.version=${version} during ProcessResources

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-automatic-expansion)

For **Maven** you can automatically expand properties from the Maven project using **resource filtering**. If you use **spring-boot-starter-parent** you can then refer to your Maven ‘project properties’ via @..@ placeholders

You can add maven project properties in your application.properties file such as

```
app.project.version=@project.version@
```

For **Gradle** you need to **expand properties from the Gradle project by configuring the Java plugin’s processResources**

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }    
}
```

Can access through placeholders.

```
app.name=${name}
app.description=${description}
app.version=${version}
```

You can use these properties to add in logback.xml

Thanks

Comment: Tried that approach (already processing .properties files, added xml) .. The problem is that I want to inject the spring application name in addition to version . So I have <springProperty name="APP_NAME" source="spring.application.name"/> in. the logback file and ${APP_NAME} ${version}. .. During process resources Gradle will try to replace all ${} fields however the process will fail due to APP_NAME not existing for gradle

Answer (score 1):

If you already managed to instruct Gradle to set `version` in the manifest file, then you could try to instruct gradle to replace `${version}` in your `logback.xml`

*I do not know Gradle, but Maven, so in Maven: it is called filtered resources, an I think it is quite the same in Gradle: [https://dzone.com/articles/resource-filtering-gradle](https://dzone.com/articles/resource-filtering-gradle_)*

Comment: Don't believe it will work when I'm also trying inject SpringProperty of my application name (it's different from the jar file) ..  <springProperty name="APP_NAME" source="spring.application.name"/>
 ${APP_NAME} ${version}  <-- in logback will fail as APP_NAME doesn't exist during processResources

Comment: Figured it out .... it's smelly ... but I use springProperty in Logback to inject the actual Spring Boot Application name (not the sub jar that contain the logback file), I use processResources, and I escape the ${APP_NAME) with /$  so that processResoruce doesn't try to populate it

Answer (score 1):

1. Added `git-commit-id-plugin` plugin in pom.xml. This creates `git.properties` at build directory and updates `META-INF` with `build-info.properties`.

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.0</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
               <goals>
                   <goal>revision</goal>
               </goals>
               <phase>initialize</phase>
           </execution>
           <execution>
               <id>validate-the-git-infos</id>
               <goals>
                   <goal>validateRevision</goal>
               </goals>
               <phase>package</phase>
           </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
           <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
           <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Added `MEATA-INF/build-info.properties` as resource in logback.xml and used the variable `${build.version}` to log the version.

   ```
   <property resource="META-INF/build-info.properties" />
   <property name="LOG_PATTERN" value="%level{length=1} %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | buildNumber=${build.version} | UserAgent = %X{User-Agent} | thread=%t | class=%c-%L | message=%msg%n" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try <%=version%> to version from gradle in application.property.

For example, you have a property `version` in application.property

```
version=<%=version%>
```

Then the source could be `'version'` in logback config.