# access buildInfo in Spring Boot 2.0 with @Value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Previously in Spring Boot 1.x, I wrote a Gradle task to copy the jar's build version to the application's `application.yml` and replaced a given property by regex, e.g. `info.build.version: 0.0.1`

Migrating to Spring Boot 2.0, I realise there's the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin allowing me to define the `buildInfo` task:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

This works and successfully displays the same information when accessing the `/info` actuator.

Now I would like to use the generated `build.version` in `META-INF/build-info.properties` in two use-cases:

1. Display the version in SwaggerUI
2. Include the version in each log line

Previously, it was enough to access the property like this: `@Value("${info.build.version:undefined}") String buildVersion`
or in `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="applicationVersion" source="info.build.version"/>
```

Unfortunately, both accessors don't work anymore, even if I replace `info.build.version` with `build.version` (as I would expect it to work).

I believe including the version in logback is just a small step away from accessing the property through the `@Value` annotation, so that's the core of my question:

How can I access the generated `build.version` in `META-INF/build-info.properties` through `@Value`?

I also tried adding the task

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('build-info.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }    
}
```

as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42051412/3105453 but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Any solution already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When it comes to `spring-boot`, Almost every information that spring handles is most likely is accessible as a spring managed bean.

For build information, `spring-boot` has a `bean` exposed for autowiring called `buildProperties`. This happens via `ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration` module.

Along with Spring Expression language (**`SpEL`**) support for `@Value` annotations, You can get the expected results as mentioned below.

```
@Value("#{buildProperties.get('version')}")           // not 'build.version'
private String myAppBuildVersion;
```

Or better, Autowire the `buildProperties` bean directly to your components so you can play with it as you want.

```
@Autowired
private BuildProperties buildProperties;
```

---

> **NOTE**: The autoconfiguration strips off the `build.` prefix. So your
>   `SpEL` expressions should use `version` as key.  Not `build.version`.

---

**UPDATE:**

I was confused by your question first because the question was more over towards how to work with `@Value` annotation. So I will leave the above answer as is.

To help you with the `logback-spring.xml`, import the `build-info.properties` into `logback-spring.xml` as shown below. This allows each key in build-info.properties to be accessed using `logback place-holders`. (DO NOT CONFUSE THIS WITH SPRING PROPERTY PLACEHOLDERS OR SPRING-EXPRESSIONS)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="appLogTarget" source="app.log.target"
    defaultValue="CONSOLE"/>
  <property resource="META-INF/build-info.properties" />


  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>[${build.version}] %d{ISO8601}" %-5p [%c{3}"] \(%t:%X{}"\) %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>
 <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>
</xml>
```

the `"resource"` property of `<properties/>` tag will look through the `classpath resources` and find the one which is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Raja, I really like your solution and I think it's a very clean one. Unfortunately, this setup requires `META-INF/build-info.properties` to be present, otherwise the mentioned bean and logback will throw errors. It's no problem to compile an artifact like this but as soon as the project is imported in my IDE (IntelliJ), the respective buildInfo task isn't run. By default, Gradle compiles to `build/`, whereas IntelliJ compiles to `out/`. I'll accept your answer since I wasn't asking for local development options.

Comment: If that's your your problem you can always configure your compilation output directories to your need...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the file `META-INF/build-info.properties` as `@PropertSource` to your Spring-Boot-Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties")
public class MyApp implements WebMvcConfigurer { 
  ...
}
```

After that you can access the property `build.version` via `@Value` in your Controller/Service/...

```
@Controller(...)
public MyController {
    @Value("${build.version}") String myVersion;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of [Spring 2.4](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4), you can use the `spring.config.import` property. For example, in `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring.config.import: "classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties"
...
sentry.version: ${build.version}
```

Similarly `@Value("${build.version}")` also works, or accessing the property in `logback-spring.xml`.