# Fiware cygnus build failure

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I wanted to use Fiware cygnus to persist data from the context broker into a CKAN instance. I've already created an orion context broker vm which is  orion-psb-image-R5.4 version 1.7.0  and a ckan VM on Fiware cloud. I began to install fiware cygnus knowing that the cygnus is based on both cygnus-common and cygnus-ngsi . So, i started by downloading the fiware-cygnus https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus
, then i began building cygnus-common successfully using maven 3.2.5 . But when i started to build cygnus-ngsi it failed although i've tried many ways to solve this but Noone worked .
Here's what i have done in details .

Firstly installing Apache Flume as described here http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.0/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html

```
$ wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/flume/1.4.0/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz
 tar xvzf apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz
$ mv apache-flume-1.4.0-bin APACHE_FLUME_HOME
$ mv APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.2.1.jar.old
$ mv APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.2.1.jar.old
$ mv APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar APACHE_FLUME_HOME/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar.old
$ mkdir -p APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/
$ mkdir APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/lib
$ mkdir APACHE_FLUME_HOME/plugins.d/cygnus/libext
```

secondly , downloading fiware-cygnus and building cygnus-common:

```
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus.git

cd fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common

mvn clean compile exec:exec assembly:single

cp target/cygnus-common-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext 

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.7.0_SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -DgroupId=com.telefonica.iot -DartifactId=cygnus-common -Dversion=1.7.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false

cp target/classes/cygnus-flume-ng /usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng
```

then i started bulding cygnus-ngsi as follows

```
cd cygnus-ngsi

mvn clean compile exec:exec assembly:single
```

and i got these results on building it:

```
[INFO] Building cygnus-ngsi 1.7.0_SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.telefonica.iot:cygnus-common:jar:1.7.0_SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.243 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-17T22:04:25+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/28M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cygnus-ngsi: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.telefonica.iot:cygnus-ngsi:jar:1.7.0_SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.telefonica.iot:cygnus-common:jar:1.7.0_SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I copied the generated jar file to the /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext as explained in the same link above by running:

```
cp cygnus-common/target/cygnus-common-1.7.0_SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar    /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext
```

also i have copied the jar file to maven repository path to make sure everything is set properly by running the command

```
cp cygnus-common/target/cygnus-common-1.7.0_SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar   ~/.m2/repository/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus-common/1.7.0
```

Now i have in the ~/.m2/repository/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus-common/1.7.0 directory two jars, the `cygnus-common-1.7.0_SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and  `cygnus-common-1.7.0.jar`  as well as the usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext directory containing them and actually i don't know whether the existence of two jars inside either of these directories would make a problem or not.

i also thought that the  cygnus-ngsi pom.xml file could be a part of the problem .. and here's the pom.xml of cygnus-ngsi:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.telefonica.iot</groupId>
    <artifactId>cygnus-ngsi</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0_SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cygnus-ngsi</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Required for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required by NGSIRestHandler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required for logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
   </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required by NameMapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Required by any agent -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.telefonica.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>cygnus-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0_SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Explicit Java version declaration in needed in some systems in which Maven seems not  -->
                <!-- being able to find itself the right version. Many systems don't need this declaration -->
                <!-- but it doesn't use to hurt anyway                                                     -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
 <fork>true</fork>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- http://www.chrissearle.org/2009/09/05/Using_maven-exec-plugin_to_store_the_current_git_sha_in_a_build/ -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>git</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>rev-parse</argument>
                            <argument>HEAD</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <outputFile>target/classes/last_git_commit.txt</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
   <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.6</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.16</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.12</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <configLocation>telefonica_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>false</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                                    <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.9</version>
                                <configuration>
                                    <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                                </configuration>
                            </plugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now i want to know what may cause this failure . All i want to do is to set a cygnus agent to use the ckansink by configuring the agent_.conf file with providing the necessary ckan parameters and then start the cygnus. and i know that this process wouldn't be completed unless the cygnus-ngsi was built successfuly

**EDIT :**  Now, i tried removing all previous cygnus files by running

```
sudo rpm -e -vv --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers cygnus
sudo rpm -e -vv --allmatches --nodeps --noscripts --notriggers cygnus-ngsi
```

And then i installed the cygnus-common and cygnus-ngsi 1.7.0 using the rpm 
and they were succesfully installed. then i configured the necessary ckan parameters in the /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf file.

The problem now is when i start the cygnus by running

```
/usr/cygnus/bin/cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /usr/cygnus/conf/ -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

i get these logs ending only with the jetty server listening on 8081 as follows:

```
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /usr/cygnus/conf/flume-env.sh
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnusagent
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-ngsi-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
time=2017-04-18T16:34:31.961Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp= | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[166] : Starting Cygnus, version 1.7.0.UNKNOWN
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.156Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.156Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.159Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.182Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:dynamodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.182Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.182Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.182Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:sth-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.182Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.187Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:dynamodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.187Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.187Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:cartodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.188Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.188Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:cartodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.188Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:mongo-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.188Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:mysql-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.190Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:mysql-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[930] : Added sinks: hdfs-sink mysql-sink ckan-sink mongo-sink sth-sink kafka-sink dynamodb-sink postgresql-sink cartodb-sink Agent: cygnus-ngsi
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.191Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:kafka-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:cartodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.192Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:kafka-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:sth-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:dynamodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.193Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.194Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:dynamodb-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.194Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:postgresql-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.194Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:postgresql-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.195Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.195Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:ckan-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.198Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:mongo-sink
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.220Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=validateConfiguration | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[140] : Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [cygnus-ngsi]
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.221Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=getConfiguration | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[138] : No configuration found for this host:cygnusagent
time=2017-04-18T16:34:32.224Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=startAllComponents | msg=org.apache.flume.node.Application[138] : Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{} channels:{} }
time=2017-04-18T16:34:33.156Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[301] : Starting a Jetty server listening on 0.0.0.0:8081 (Management Interface)
```

and when i test the cygnus from another terminal with a notification.sh testing file i get connection refused.

```
[centos@orcb2 ~]$ ./notification.sh http://localhost:5050/notify
* About to connect() to localhost port 5050 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Although the configuration files are supposed to be correct as i think
and they are as follows:

- these are my agent_1.conf file source and ckan configuration parameters :

  ```
  =============================================
  source configuration

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = hdfs-channel mysql-channel ckan-channel mongo-channel sth-channel kafka-channel dynamodb-channel postgresql-channel


  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder

  cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf



     # ============================================
      NGSICKANSink configuration
  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.type =com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_grouping = false

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_name_mappings = false

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.enable_encoding = false

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx
  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = http://130.206.120.212

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = 8080

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_viewer = recline_grid_view

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.orion_url = http://localhost:1026

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.attr_persistence = row

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ssl = false

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 30

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_ttl = 10

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.backend.max_conns = 500

  cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.backend.max_conns_per_route = 100
  ```

and this is my cygnus_instance_1.conf

```
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus

CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf

AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent

LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

ADMIN_PORT=8081

POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

So, is missing in the whole configurations and what could be fixed to let the httpsource accept my notification requests ?

Comment: Hope you can answer it @frb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this command:

```
cp target/cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext
```

It seems you have built cygnus-common release 1.1.0 (Is it right? I mean, is there a `cygnus-common-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file within `target/` directory?)

Nevertheless, in the next command you have tried to install cygnus-common release 1.7.0_SNAPSHOT (with dependencies):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.7.0_SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -DgroupId=com.telefonica.iot -DartifactId=cygnus-common -Dversion=1.7.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=false
```

Thus one of the above commands is wrong: both must refer to the same release.

One question: once cloned the github repo, did you checkout to a specific version as stated in the documentation?

> $ git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus.git
>   
> $ cd fiware-cygnus
>   
> $ git checkout <branch>

Such a `<branch>` could be `master` (the lastest development, not recommended), `1.7.0` (the latest official release), `1.6.0`...

So, use always a specific version for all the components, even use the appropiate documentation version (for instance, the documentation link you have posted refers to release 1.3.0, while you were trying to build cygnus-common 1.1.0 but installing 1.7.0...).

PS: there is an easy way of installing the latest release (at the moment of writing this, 1.7.0): using a [RPM](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_rpm/) from FIWARE repo.

**EDIT 1: [Once installation problems are fixed and the question has been edited regarding a startup problem]**

If you are not able to send a simulated notification to Cygnus it is because Cygnus has not started properly. You can check the logs at `/var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log` and get more details. Anyway, some remarks to your configuration:

Regarding `agent_1.conf`:

- I'm missing source, channel and sink  declarations. In addition, I'm missing the channel configuration. I guess you consciously omitted it, for simplicity.
- Source channels can be limited to `ckan-channel`.

Regarding `cygnus_instance_1.conf`:

- `AGENT_NAME` must match the one used in `agent_1.conf`, i.e. `cygnus-ngsi`.

Additionally, once installed, did you started Cygnus service? Just to be sure :)

```
$ sudo service cygnus start
```

Comment: i apologize about it , i have built 1.7.0 but i made a typo here and i edited the line. In fact i didn't make the checkout . and how do i exactly choose the appropriate version in order to avoid such an error ? . I just want to use a version that doesn't make problems in building and works correctly with ckan. and is  installing 1.7.0 cygnus-common and cygnus-ngsi using rpm sufficient to let the cygnus work with the ckan immediately ?
So, what do you recommend for me ?

Comment: No worries :) Install using the RPM, that will install 1.7.0, the latest stable version. It will work with CKAN.

Comment: Well , now i have removed all files relating to any previous cygnus version and installed cygnus common & ngsi  1.7.0  using rpm and i have accurately configured my agent_1.conf file for ckan. Now when i start cygnus i think it's not listening on port 5050 as it doesn't accept my testing requests and i've edited the question above with my current case @frb

Comment: Are you running all in the same host ([centos@`orcb2` ~]$) ? If not, you will have to change `localhost` by the right ip you need.

Comment: yes i'm running them all in the same  vm  as it's a fiware image and accordingly the localhost  parameter is supposed to be correct

Comment: @frb , i edited my question in an answer below due to the question's body limitation .. i solved the http connection refused issue but still there are errors in the logs as the data is still not persisted .. i provided the logs below and i provided the missing declarations you requested previously perhaps something needs to be changed. .

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2** : i've solved the connection refused error after i noticed that the default naming in cygnus_instance_1.conf is cygnusagent meanwhile the used one inside the agent_1.conf was cygnus-ngsi and i changed the name in the instance file. and now i get successfull http response , but still the data isn't persisted in ckan as i noticed some errors in the cygnus logs (whether i started cygnus by either the "service cygnus start" or the other long startup command)  .

Now, this is the successful response as follows:

```
  [centos@orcb2 ~]$ ./notification.sh http://localhost:5050/notify
    * About to connect() to localhost port 5050 (#0)
    *   Trying ::1... connected
    * Connected to localhost (::1) port 5050 (#0)
    > POST /notify HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
    > Host: localhost:5050
    > Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    > Accept: application/json
    > Fiware-Service: gp
    > Fiware-ServicePath: /gp
    > Content-Length: 607
    > 
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    < Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
    < 
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
    * Closing connection #0
```

and here are the important parts regarding the errors in the new logs when i start the cygnus send notification:

```
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /usr/cygnus/conf/flume-env.sh
Warning: JAVA_HOME is not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.log.file=cygnus.log -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp '/usr/cygnus/conf:/usr/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/*:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/*' -Djava.library.path= com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication -p 8081 -f /usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf -n cygnus-ngsi
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/lib/cygnus-ngsi-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/cygnus/plugins.d/cygnus/libext/cygnus-common-1.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
time=2017-04-19T21:43:39.994Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp= | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[166] : Starting Cygnus, version 1.7.0.UNKNOWN
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.136Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.139Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.141Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_1.conf
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.166Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:dynamodb-sink
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.166Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:hdfs-sink
/bin/bash: indent: command not found
.
.
.


   time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.364Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICartoDBSink[242] : [cartodb-sink] Error while creating the CartoDB persistence backend. Details: /usr/cygnus/conf/cartodb_keys.conf (No such file or directory)
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.364Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[344] : [cartodb-sink] Startup completed. Nevertheless, there are errors in the configuration, thus this sink will not run the expected logic
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.378Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[354] : [postgresql-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.386Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIPostgreSQLSink[201] : [postgresql-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.379Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[354] : [mongo-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.379Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[354] : [sth-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.389Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<init> | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.CygnusGroupingRules[53] : Grouping rules read:
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.403Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<init> | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.CygnusGroupingRules[61] : Grouping rules syntax has errors. Details: null
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.405Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[354] : [mysql-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.457Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<init> | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.CygnusGroupingRules[53] : Grouping rules read:
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.457Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=<init> | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.CygnusGroupingRules[61] : Grouping rules syntax has errors. Details: null
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.744Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[354] : [kafka-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.867Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:5050: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.868Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed Server@15e1356d: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.868Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource[154] : Error while starting HTTPSource. Exception follows.
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.start(HTTPSource.java:151)
        at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
        at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
time=2017-04-19T21:43:40.894Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable[253] : Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource{name:http-source,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
        at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.start(HTTPSource.java:155)
        at org.apache.flume.source.EventDrivenSourceRunner.start(EventDrivenSourceRunner.java:44)
        at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.start(HTTPSource.java:151)
        ... 9 more


.
.
.


 time=2017-04-19T21:43:41.136Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[301] : Starting a Jetty server listening on 0.0.0.0:8081 (Management Interface)
time=2017-04-19T21:43:41.173Z | lvl=WARN | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=warn | msg=org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog[76] : failed SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
/bin/bash: indent: command not found
time=2017-04-19T21:43:41.174Z | lvl=FATAL | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.http.JettyServer[90] : Fatal error running the Management Interface. Details=Address already in use
time=2017-04-19T21:43:41.446Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=start | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[354] : [dynamodb-sink] Startup completed
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.169Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=run | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication$YAFS[457] : Thread found not alive, exiting Cygnus. ID=41, name=Thread-21
Starting an ordered shutdown of Cygnus
Stopping sources
Stopping http-source (lyfecycle state=IDLE)
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.173Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[139] : Component type: SOURCE, name: http-source stopped
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.173Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[145] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. source.start.time == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.173Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[151] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. source.stop.time == 1492638222173
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.174Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append-batch.accepted == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.179Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append-batch.received == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.180Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append.accepted == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.180Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.append.received == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.180Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.events.accepted == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.180Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.events.received == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.180Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: SOURCE, name: http-source. src.open-connection.count == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:43:42.181Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource[172] : Http source http-source stopped. Metrics: SOURCE:http-source{src.events.accepted=0, src.events.received=0, src.append.accepted=0, src.append-batch.accepted=0, src.open-connection.count=0, src.append-batch.received=0, src.append.received=0}
All the channels are empty
Stopping channels
.
.
.

Stopping ckan-channel (lyfecycle state=START)
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.482Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[139] : Component type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel stopped
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.482Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[145] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.start.time == 1492638220354
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.482Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[151] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.stop.time == 1492638250482
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.482Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.capacity == 1000
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.483Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.current.size == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.483Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.event.put.attempt == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.483Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.event.put.success == 0
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.483Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.event.take.attempt == 5
time=2017-04-19T21:44:10.483Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=stop | msg=org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup[167] : Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: ckan-channel. channel.event.take.success == 0
.
.
.
Stopping sinks
Stopping ckan-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping postgresql-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping dynamodb-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping kafka-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping cartodb-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping hdfs-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping mongo-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping mysql-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
Stopping sth-sink (lyfecycle state=START)
```

These are the channel , source and sink definitions in the agent.conf file

```
agent.sources = seqGenSrc
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = loggerSink

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type = seq

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels = memoryChannel

agent.sinks.loggerSink.type = logger

agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel = memoryChannel

agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory


agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100
```

and this this is the ckan channel configuration

```
cygnus-ngsi.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory
cygnus-ngsi.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Regarding the ckan side , I want to know if there are additional procedures in the Ckan more than creating the account to persist the ngsi events.. do i have to manually create an organization and a dataset with its datastore for receiving ngsi events ? or are the fiware service and service path mapped  into an organization and dataset with creation of their datastore and resource automatically on sending ngsi events ? i just want to make sure if i understood this correctly.

Now , what do you think i shall do to solve these errors ?

Comment: Most of the error traces are given by the Carto sink (the keys configuration file is missing) and many other sinks different than CKAN. Neverhteless, I understand you don't need the, thus simply remove that configuration from `agent_1.conf` :) I mean, Cygnus agent template contains the skeleton for all the available sinks, but in the practice you don't need everything except the configuration required by your chosen sink.

Comment: Regarding the `Address already in use (Bind failed)`, that is because some other Unix process is using the 5050 TCP port. Most probably, another instance of Cygnus from another previous run that was not properly killed or stopped. Please, check which process is using such port by running `sudo netstat -nap|grep 5050` and check which is the process by running `ps -ef|grep <PID shown by netstat command>`. If it is another Cygnus instance, kill it by doing `sudo kill -9 <PID>`. If it is another process you want to maintain, simply change the port in Cygnus configuration (e.g. 5051).

Comment: Thanks so much @frb . i finally could persist the data into ckan by subscription to the orion as i solved the rest of the issues when i fixed a parameter in the configuration file .  you helped me in every step and i'm really grateful :))

Comment: Nice to hear that! :)