# How to read programatically the version of a dependency used by the parent in java?

Tags: java, pom.xml

I want to read the version that is used by the parent of my application.
I try to write the version dynamically in the `pom` of the child.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'parent' and 'child'. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: you can read the parent's pom xml using Jaxb and then read the properties of the dependency section to read the values.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve version from maven pom.xml in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set version on a child pom since it inherits its parent version.

On the example below, the **bar-child** project inherits the 1.0 version attribute from it's parent **bar**:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>bar-child</artifactId>
</project>
```

By the way, along the child pom configuration you can always type **${project.version}** to reference the version number, which, as explained before, will be the same version as it's parent (1.0).

Check https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance for more information.