# getResourceAsStream returns null when reading properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to load application.properties file form maven resource folder but `getResourceAsStream` returns **null**. here is my code:

```
static {
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    InputStream in = Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("application.properties");
    props.load(in);
}
```

but `InputStream` is **null**. `Configuration` class is located at `org.elasticsearch.utils` package and `application.properties` is located at `src/main/resources`. What is wrong?

Comment: No, this is completely different case.

Comment: @Logan I already saw the link but that did not help me

Comment: @Nariman: How do you start the application? From the jar? From IDE?

Comment: @mentallurg in both situations I'm getting null. I shlould add that this is an elasticsearch plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read a classpath resource relative to the `Configuration` class.

- If you want to do this, the resource must be on the same relative path, i.e. your property file must be in `src/main/resources/org/elasticsearch/utils`.
- Or you can instead use absolute path: `/application.properties`.

Comment: I tried both ways as you said but still getting null.

Comment: Jeri, you dont understand how IDEs work and how they map directories to classpath.

Comment: @mentallurg the use of `src/main/resources` standard directory structure strongly hints at using Maven. If that's the case, the used IDE shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JiriTousek after I moved resource file, should I use Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("application.properties") or Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("org/elasticsearch/utils/application.properties") ?

Comment: @NarimanEsmaielyFard when you open the compiled `jar` (open, not launch - it's a ZIP archive), what path the property file is on, within the jar?

Comment: @NarimanEsmaielyFard if you moved it to `src/main/resources/org/elasticsearch/utils`, you keep the `application.properties` path.

Comment: @JiriTousek using Configuration.class.getResourceAsStream("org/elasticsearch/utils/application.properties") worked. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From what I am seeing, your setup is just right. Having the maven resource folder and the java folder both under "main" is totally fine.
I had a problem with the filename of the properties file. I still do not understand why, but as soon I changed the name from `application.properties` to `whateverYouWant.properties` it suddenly works.

And have you enabled filtering for maven resources in the pom.xml?

```
    <build>

    <!--Allows access to maven resources-->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Here is a guide from Alex Miller [Retrieve version from maven pom.xml in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code)

And here is the full code example for accessing the properties in java code (I know you posted already nearly all of it, but just in case if somebody stumbles upon this post)

```
    public String getVersionNumber() {
    String version = "";
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("main.properties"));
        version = properties.getProperty("application.version");
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Version number could not be retrieved from maven resources.");
    } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
        log.log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot find .properties file to read version number");
    }
     return version;
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem with `application.properties'. Now renamed it to `app.properties` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have tried and working: [image]

@Jiri's answer is also correct.

PS: `"/config.properties"` also works in my example. But if the this was inside ElasticTest class, then you should have to use just `"config.properties"`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to either add a / at the beginning of the rsource location string or move it to match the package structure or use the classloader rather than the class.

When looking for a resource via a class the assumption is that the resource directory structure mirrors your class structure.

so your code is looking for the resource under
src/main/resources/org/elastic...

Comment: Meir, you are wrong, you dont understand how IDEs work.

Comment: still getting null!

Answer (score -1):

1. If the file "application.properties" is under "src/main/resources", use full path (in the sense of class loader):

   getResourceAsStream("/application.properties")
2. If you move your file to the same package as your class, you can use relative path:

   getResourceAsStream("application.properties")
3. If you move your file to the same other packages, use full path:

   getResourceAsStream("/my/package/name/application.properties")