# Putting maven project build version in mdc

Tags: java, maven, mdc

I am working on a java spring boot application made through maven.

Suppose my pom.xml has version 2.1.205.
I want it to put into [slf4j MDC](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#mdc), so that with every log being printed, my version of current build should be printed.

Comment: Good, you identified the problem and narrow down to MDC, did you tried anything with MDC?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you generate a jar with a properties file exposing the version number in it, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697482/6309).

Then, following "[Use MDC (Mapping Diagnostic Context) in your log](https://medium.com/sipios/how-to-use-log4j-and-mdc-in-java-spring-boot-application-26b1a77f5c3e#83b9)" from **[Moulin Raphaël](https://twitter.com/rmoulin_k)**, define a pattern layout in your `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%clr{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{faint} %clr{%5p} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{%X}{faint} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n%xwEx"> </PatternLayout>
```

> This Map is displayed in the logs if the `%X` mask is used in the Log4j message format definition.
>   This is the case here in our `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` file.

Write a CommandLineRunner which will put the right value in your loglogger.

```
package com.yourapp.mdc;

...
import org.slf4j.MDC;

@Component
public class Execute implements CommandLineRunner {
    ... 

    public void run(String... args) {
        MDC.put("Version", "Version as read from properties file");
        log.info("Test Log4j with MDC");
    }
}
```

You can use that logger elsewhere with:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);
```